# A sequence of embedded closed balls that have empty intersection

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm reading soviet textbook "Elements of theory of functions and functional analysis" by Kolmogorov and Fomin. There is an exercise is in it: show example of  complete metric space and a sequence of embedded closed balls, that have *empty* intersection". I understand, that sequence of their diameters must not converge, but I could not find the example. I was thinking about space of infinite sequences $(x_1,x_2, x_3, \dots): |x_i|<=1$with distance between x and y $\rho(x,y)=max(|x_i-y_i|)_i$, and sequence of balls with radius 1 and centers $x_0=(0,0,\dots), x_1=(1,0,0,\dots), x_2=(1,1,0,\dots),etc$. But is it correct?

Comment: What counts as a sequence? Do the balls have to be nested?

Comment: The first answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388930/intersection-of-open-balls-in-a-metric-space) will help.

Comment: @DavidMitra, yes, this is the answer, I guess, thanks a lot.